# interesting tags not just on front page

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

I think it'd be very useful if my `interesting tags` that are on the front page travel with me to the `tag page`, `single question page` etc...
that way I don't have to keep going back to the front page to click them.

I hope you know what I mean.

sorry for the wp analogy.

Answer (score 1):

For "tag page" — scroll a little more, it is right below Related Tags.

[image]

Comment: thanks @kenny, i never saw that on the tag page. now only if there was a way to drag that up to the top. but thanks though. now we have to get it to go to the question page.